# How to thread a type through wrapping classes properly?

Tags: scala

```
trait Thing {
  type Out
  def get: Out
}

case class Wrapper(t: Thing) extends Thing {
  type Out = t.Out
  override def get = t.get
}

def hey(t: Thing): t.Out = Wrapper(t).get
```

This gives me a type error, though it is obviously type safe. I'm wondering how I can properly prove to the compiler that this is safe without having to do a cast.

Any ideas?

Comment: Using `def hey(t: Thing): Thing#Out = Wrapper(t).get` works for me

Comment: This compiles, but it is no better than the cast really.scala> hey(new Thing { type Out = Int; def get = 1})
res2: Thing#Out = 1
So you don't get a useful static type

Answer (score 5):

If you really, really don't want to put a type parameter on `Wrapper`, you can roll your own fake case class with a less forgetful `apply`:

```
trait Thing {
  type Out
  def get: Out
}

abstract class Wrapper(t: Thing) extends Thing

object Wrapper {
  def apply(t: Thing): Wrapper { type Out = t.Out } =
    new Wrapper(t) {
      type Out = t.Out
      def get: Out = t.get
    }
}

def hey(t0: Thing): t0.Out = Wrapper(t0: Thing { type Out = t0.Out }).get
```

(In real life you'd also want to define all the other stuff that case classes give you—useful equality, etc.)

The problem is that the `Wrapper.apply` that's automatically generated when you define a case class just returns a `Wrapper`, which means the compiler has lost all static information about its `Out`. If you write your own `apply`, you can hold on to that information by making the return type a refinement type that specifies the `Out`.

To demonstrate that it works:

```
scala> val myThing = new Thing {
     |   type Out = String
     |   def get = "foo"
     | }
myThing: Thing{type Out = String} = $anon$1@5e265ba4

scala> hey(myThing)
res0: myThing.Out = foo

scala> val foo: String = hey(myThing)
foo: String = foo
```

So the compiler is able to track the fact that the `Out` is `String` all the way through.

Comment: I see...this makes sense

Comment: As always, extremely helpful.

Comment: Very nice. The purpose of the wrapper is just to project Out preserving the type, right?

Comment: @GClaramunt The purpose of the wrapper is the OP's business. :) But right, assuming you want this kind of wrapping class, that's what the Wrapper.`apply` here does.